# dont working $.ajax by post method to controller action always happend like get

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with jQuery ajax.
Using  default MVC project in VS 2013
i can not make ajax request by post method.(pass  LoginViewModel to Account Controller)
can give me  example?

I look lot peaces of code using ajax with "POST" and it is look simple but 
not working in my situation. I dont want using "Ajax.BeginForm"
Thanks.

```
$.fn.loginAA = function (args) {
        this.html('<div class="ajaxlogin_container"><form action="/Account/Login" method="post" id="ajaxlogin_action"><header id="ajaxlogin_header">Please Log in...</header><div><input type="text" placeholder="Username" required id="ajaxlogin_username" /></div><div><input type="password" placeholder="Password" required id="ajaxlogin_password" /></div><div id="progress"><input type="submit" value="Log in" id="ajaxlogin_submit" /></div></form></div>');
        $("#ajaxlogin_action").submit(function () {
            var loginViewModel = { UserName: "Alex", Password: "12345", RememberMe: true };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Account/Login",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: loginViewModel
            });
         });
        return this; 
    };

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

end

```
  $("#login").bind("click", function () {
            $(".containet").loginAA()
```

So I can't execute Login action by Ajax

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of what did you try?

Comment: Is this using a `WebApiConfig` -- if so, post your config -- Web API post methods can only take 1 parameter which should either map to an object or a simple type - else you'll get a nice error in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by the question writer :

> account controller had an attribute [Authorize] therefore I can not
>   using post action - Login(LoginViewModel model) through ajax. and in
>   script after ajax method I've added this.preventDefault(); now all
>   good. Thanks

Comment: Where did you get this answer?

Comment: "Answer by the question writer" (now i see he edited his question probably due to my answer, cause he wrote this quote in his question )